# Container doesn't start

Tags: docker, debian, containers

I have a container that doesn't start when I start, have this error:

```
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:495: container init caused: process_linux.go:458: setting cgroup config for procHooks process caused: can't load program: invalid argument: unknown
Error: failed to start containers: NMP1
```

The version of S.O is  4.14.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.14.12-2kali1 (2018-01-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux and the version of docker  20.10.5+dfsg1, build 55c4c88

Anyone can help me ?

A greeting and thanks

Comment: Please consider including the specifics as to how you're starting the container.  From the error, it seems as if you're starting it with invalid parameters.

Comment: Run `docker ps -a` then find the name or id of exited container. Now run `docker logs container_name` or `docker logs container_id`

Comment: Please post the run command.